# Adding new article to transactional replication gives error at subscriber

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactional-replication

I have a updatable transactional replication set with SQL Server 2008. Everything is working fine.

I added a new table to the existing publication through `sp_addarticle` followed by `sp_addsubscription`. After that I ran the Snapshot Agent. The snapshot has been generated only for newly added table. So the new table was successfully replicated to subscriber. I could even able to replicate a newly inserted record into new table to subscriber.

But it's not possible viceversa. When I insert a record into new table in the subscriber database, I am getting an error

> Msg 515 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'msrepl_tran_version', table Servername.dbo.Tablename'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.'.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Many thanks in advance.
Geeta

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you that the default value for the msrepl_tran_version table has not been set on the subscriber database (or that you're willingly trying to set the column to NULL in your INSERT statement).  It needs to have a default value of newid().  Why that didn't get set though I am unsure.